# Install latest versions in Centos 7/RHEL 7

Tags: centos7, yum, rhel7

I'm having trouble with installing the latest versions for many packages, for instance `vim`.
There is version 8.1 in [their website](https://vim8.org/) however when I run `yum search vim` the latest version I can find is `vim-enhanced:7.4.160`.
I understand the stability and security issues with upgrading the versions but being used to a rolling-release distro (archlinux) I'd like to have the latest versions for my development tools.
I tried enabling more repositories such as: elrepol, epel, elrepo-extras but they don't seem to have the latest versions for the packages too.

Comment: I suggest read `https://www.vim.org/git.php` section **Building Vim**. Building from source will be the best option in Your case.

Comment: There is no one answer to this that would be true for all packages. There are [a large number of official, semi-official, and compatible package repositories](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories?action=show&redirect=Repositories). One of them might, or might not, have the particular version of the particular package you want. If you want to always have access to bleeding edge software, you might be better off sticking to a different distro.

Answer (score 1):

This is what (Red Hat) Software Collections and Developer Toolset exist for. Though they don't include Vim, there's a lot of developer tooling (compilers, dynamic languages, databases, ...) in much fresher versions than in default repositories.

Default packages and software collections packages can be installed and used alongside each other without conflicts.

Check out:

- RHEL: [Red Hat Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/) & [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview/)
- CentOS: [Software Collections](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) ([also at softwarecollections.org](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/user/rhscl/)), which includes Developer Toolset